# Deploying custom bytecode on the blockchain

Tags: contract-deployment, bytecode

Say I have custom bytecode which I want to deploy to the blockchain, for example, `0x6009` (`PUSH1 0x09`) and I want to create a contract which executes exactly that bytecode when called. As far as I understand, I can send a transaction to the all zeros address (or rather, no specifying an address at all) to achieve this.

However in this contract-creating transaction, I have to send bytecode that returns the bytecode which I actually want to deploy. Are there any tools to create this bytecode? If not, how to I wrap given bytecode so that I can deploy it on the blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy a contract, you need a message/transaction of type "contract creation", i.e. without receiver. Moreover, the "input" of the transaction should contain a snippet of code, whose objective is to "return" (`0xf3`) the persistent code.

So the idea is to use `CODECOPY` or simply `MSTORE` the part of information (`0x6009`) you need and afterward call `RETURN`, which takes from memory the output that will persist on the blockchain.

### USING MSTORE

In your particular example, you could write (there are surely more efficient ways to do it, as with Solidity):

```
 1. PUSH 60 // 6060
 2. PUSH 0  // 6060
 3. MSTORE8 // 53
 4. PUSH 09 // 6009
 5. PUSH 1  // 6001
 6. MSTORE8 // 53
 7. PUSH 0  // 6000
 8. PUSH 2  // 6002
 9. RETURN  // f3
```

**COMMENT**

1. Instructions 1-3, store in the first byte of memory `0x60`
2. Instructions 4-6, store in the second byte of memory `0x09`
3. Instructions 7-9, returns the first two byte of memory (`0` is the start index, `2` is the length)

### USING CODECOPY

```
1. PUSH 2  // length of code to copy in memory
2. PUSH 0xD // offset of "init" code
3. PUSH 0  // offset in memory, i.e. where to store
4. CODECOPY 
5. PUSH 0  // offset in memory to copy
6. PUSH 2  // length of memory to return (i.e. the length of body, 2 in your case)
7. RETURN
8. PUSH 09 // Here push is intepreted as a simple number
```

This version is more versatile, indeed, you can keep the first 7 instructions (you have only to change the length of bytes to copy) and then you can have arbitrary code.

### Note

To have an insight you can inspect the source code of a little contract with REMIX:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract foo {
    constructor() public payable {

    }
}
```

N.B. the constructor is marked payable, otherwise the constructor is far more complicated because it requires to check the input money.

N.B.2: you must be careful with jumps ^^, because the pc to which you have to jump does not correspond to the one of the source code (you have to remove the constructor offset).